# How can I export a list of association rules to txt or Excel in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, export, market-basket-analysis

```
association_results = filter(lambda rule: len(rule.lhs) == 1, rules)
for rule in sorted(association_results, key=lambda rule: rule.lift):
  print(rule)
```

This code will print all the association rules like this in a list (Can't show data due to security):

> {Product 1} -> {Product 2} (conf: 0.526, supp: 0.001, lift: 264.188, conv: 2.107)

However, I need this list with rules to be exported to a txt file or preferably to Excel. But when I use this code to export it to export it to excel, it gives me an error.

```
[In] : association_results.to_excel('results.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
[Out]: AttributeError: 'filter' object has no attribute 'to_excel
```

Can someone tell me how to correctly export my output to txt or Excel?

Comment: What's your intended output

Comment: @Datanovice The same output as it shows in my notebook. Per row the association rule.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use this code:

```
OutputPath = r'C:/Users/..../.spyder-py3/OutPuts'

WriteExcelPackagePath = r'C:/Users/.../.spyder-py3/PyExcelerate-0.9.0'
os.chdir(WriteExcelPackagePath)
from pyexcelerate import Workbook
Wb = Workbook()
Wb.new_sheet("MyResultData", data=MyResultData.values )
Wb.save(OutputPath +"/MyResultData.xlsx")
```

You should Copy this package (PyExcelerate-0.9.0) in the path

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow! I believe you code doesn't solve the author's problem. Note that he works with `filter` object, and not with a dataframe (thus `.values` wouldn't work). 

You should adapt the code to the use case in question (and optimally, explain the error in the author's code). However, I believe there is a simpler answer that doesn't require additional dependencies.